# How to use substr_replace at multiple positions?

Tags: php, string, substring

I have a telephone number and I would like to add 2 spaces into the string, I am using substr_replace multiple times to achieve this. Is this possible with one use.

```
$telephone = "07974621779";
$telephone1 = substr_replace($telephone, " ", 3, 0);
$telephone2 = substr_replace($telephone1, " ", 8, 0);

echo $telephone2; //outputs 079 7462 1779
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any of these will do the job:

```
$telephone = "07974621779";
$telephone=substr_replace(substr_replace($telephone," ",3,0)," ",8,0);
// sorry still two function calls, but fewer lines and variables
echo $telephone; //outputs 079 7462 1779
```

Or

```
$telephone="07974621779";
$telephone=preg_replace('/(?<=^\d{3})(\d{4})/'," $1 ",$telephone);
// this uses a capture group and is less efficient than the following pattern
echo $telephone; //outputs 079 7462 1779
```

Or

```
$telephone="07974621779";
$telephone=preg_replace('/^\d{3}\K\d{4}/',' $0 ',$telephone);
// \K restarts the fullstring match ($0)
echo $telephone; //outputs 079 7462 1779
```

Or

```
$telephone = preg_replace('/(?=(?:\d{4}){1,2}$)/', ' ', $telephone);
```

Or even

```
$telephone = implode(' ', sscanf($telephone, '%3s%4s%4s'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you cannot just input arrays as start and end values like this:

```
$telephone1 = substr_replace($telephone, " ", array(3, 8), array(0, 0));
```

This means that you probably need to write your own wrapper function:

```
function substr_replace_mul($string, $replacement, $start, $end) {
   // probably do some error/sanity checks
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($start); $i++) {
       $string = substr_replace($string, $replacement, $start[$i], is_array($end) ? $end[$i] : $end);
   }

   return $string;
}
```

Usage:

```
$telephone1 = substr_replace_mul($telephone, " ", array(3, 8), 0);
```

Warning: Written in the browser and completly untested, but i think you get the idea.